# square bracket appended when list of object is passed from view(jsp) to controller

Tags: java, jsp

I am passing an object from view (jsp) to controller .
the object is actually aa list , but when i iterate it in the controller, i get a square bracket prepended and appended for the first and  last element of the list, any idea what might be the reason ?

```
<input type="hidden" name="customObjectList" value="${vobject.getCustomObjectList}" />
```

When i extract this in controller:

```
"@RequestParam(required = true, value = " customObjectList" ) List <CustomObject> objectList
```

when i iterate object, and print a field , i get a square bracket prepended and appended.

```
for(CustomObject object: objectList)
{
    sout(object.getField());
}
```

Output

[value1
value2
value3]

Any idea how this can be avoided ?

Comment: What is the type of `field`?

Comment: field is of type String

Comment: You can't store array in single input field.

Comment: how do you suggest acessing it, if is extract it in controller as a String, i can split it - the string is something like ['val2','val1']

Comment: No. Iterate your list and create multiple input type with same name and store each array value. I post it as answer

Comment: did not get you..

Comment: Plz see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<c:forEach var="customObject" items="${vobject.getCustomObjectList}">
    <td>
<input type="hidden" name="customObjectList" value= <c:out value="${customObject.getField()}" /> />

    </td>
</c:forEach>
```

Try something like this. Spring will put input name customObjectList values into that array nicely!